# Splitting fields out of a log file with Powershell

Tags: powershell

Relatively new to Powershell, so this is probably going to be a pretty simple question for anyone more seasoned with it.

I've got some log files (for an AWS S3 bucket) which contain a bunch of text fields separated by spaces (yeah...). The logs are created every 20 seconds or so in separate files, so a month's worth of logs is over 100,000 files.

I need to download them all in one go, and merge them all into a single file so I can copy it into an Amazon Redshift database. This part is fine. I'm using the AWS command line tool to sync a local folder with the S3 bucket, with include and exclude filters to get the logs I want, then the following to write only the entries containing "OBJECT" into the combined file:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -include "*" | % { Get-Content $_ -ReadCount 0 | Select-String "OBJECT" | Add-Content logfiles\printlogs2017-09.txt }
```

However, the resultant file is over 700MB and although that will still work, and I could extract what I want once it's in Redshift, in truth, I only really need three fields from it, so I might as well only write those three fields into the merged file.

I figured that given the lines are separated by spaces, this is really just like splitting up a sentence into words, and plucking only select words from it, so tried to do this by putting a line at a time into a variable, then using foreach and split() to divide that line into an array of fields, then output only the fields I want, but every combination I've tried either errors because I've got the parameters or the structure of a pipeline (it should be noted here that I don't yet understand pipelines) wrong, or it doesn't output anything because the array is somehow empty.

How can I edit the above line of code to include a part which splits each line of the source on space, then only writes certain items of the resulting array (I think it's 7, 8, and 10) to the new file, separated by commas. Ultimately, I'm after something along the lines of (and I know this is wrong):

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -include "2017-09-01-00*" | % { $lines = (Get-Content $_) | foreach { $fields = $_.split(" "); Set-Content ($fields[7] + ',' + $fields[8] + ',' + $fields[10]) } | Add-Content logfiles\printlogs2017-09-test.txt }
```

And what I want at the end is: field7,field8,field10

Comment: Are you able to include a sample of the logs? Might be easier to understand the issue that way.

Comment: Not en exact sample, no. They contain too much sensitive information. But in truth, the content doesn't really matter. It's a load of strings, with spaces. Just think of them as sentences. They look uniformly like this for a single line:

`e211a6bb2bbcfa29822a400c4c05ba18cae3e73322862922db4e477e83b7b10e some-kind-of-url [dd/MM/yyyy:hh:mm:ss +0000] 1.23.1.49 arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/user-id 83A823B93D923R REST.PUT.OBJECT 20170901/folder/subfolder/documentname.pdf PUT/20170901/folder/subfolder/documentname.pdf 200 - - 348247 119 48 - aws-sdk-java/1.4.4.1-linux/some.long/software/version-id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a couple of possible options for you, both which generate you a single CSV (which is what I assumed you wanted).

**Option 1:** Creating a custom object from the split and then output that and pipe it in to `Export-CSV`:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -include "2017-09-01-00*" | ForEach-Object { 
    Get-Content $_ | ForEach-Object { 
        $fields = $_.split(' ')
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Field7 = $fields[7]
            Field8 = $fields[8]
            Field10 = $fields[10]
        }
    }
} | Export-CSV logfiles\printlogs2017-09-test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

---

**Option 2:** Use `Import-CSV` with a defined header line (which is optional if your log file already has a header line) and with the delimiter specified as a space, filter with `Select-Object` to get the desired fields and then export via `Export-CSV`:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -include "2017-09-01-00*" | ForEach-Object { 
    Import-CSV $_ -Delimiter ' ' -Header 'Field0','Field1','Field2','Field3','Field4','Field5','Field6','Field7','Field8','Field9','Field10' | Select Field7,Field8,Field10
} | Export-CSV logfiles\printlogs2017-09-test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Obviously you can customize the field names in both to suit your data.

I'd recommend the second option because relying on array items being present is always a bit risky.

Comment: These look useful. What would be the difference between kind of blindly relying on array items being present, and blindly relying on fields being present in the source file? Does split() have some inconsistent behaviour compared to setting -Delimiter on the Import-CSV command?

Comment: Oh, also, does that second option write the Headers every time too, or just use them at the import stage? I wouldn't want to write 100,000 header rows throughout the merged output ;)

Comment: The main difference is that if you rely on the array item and its not present you'll get a big red error message, where as if you rely on the field being present and its not you'll just get an empty entry in the CSV and no error (I think).

Comment: It will use them as input and output, but it should just write them once as `Export-CSV` is on the end of the outer loop (note I didn't have it this way originally).

Comment: Btw if your log file already has headers then you don't need to specify them, just use -delimiter and specify the column names you want in the `Select` as appropriate and you should be golden.

Comment: Great, thanks Mark. I've implemented the second option with a defined set of field names and it seems to be working a treat for a small set of files. I'm going to run it over the full set now and see what happens.

Comment: `-Header (0..10|foreach{"Field$_"})`

Comment: Nice :) although I assumed he’d want to put in real header names